# Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $ l.164 ...1)^{k+1} |A_i1 \cap . . . \cap A_ik| $ .}

Tags: math-mode, errors, missing

Error message:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.164 ...1)^{k+1} |A_i1 \cap . . . \cap A_ik| $ .}
```

my code:

```
$ |A1 \cup . . . \cup An| = \sum_{k=1}^{\n} \sun_{1 \leq i_1 \leq ...\leq i_k \leq n} (-1)^{k+1} |A_i1 \cap . . . \cap A_ik| $
```

Comment: please clarify your question and make your code a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mistyped `\sum` and `\n` instead of `n`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$ |A1 \cup \dots \cup An| = 
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq \dots\leq i_k \leq n} (-1)^{k+1} |A_i1 \cap \dots \cap A_ik| $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps use `\dots` instead of `...` as well.